# Replace Thumbnails and Theme Switching

Tags: firefox-addon

I am currently making an extension, and I hope I could get some
practical advice on feasibility :

I want my extension to go fetch/load a local folder of custom homescreen
thumbnails(top-sites), and then replace the auto-generated thumbnails in
the homescreen with those it loaded.
The extension would be able to read the associated domain names of the
thumbnails and then replace them accordingly.

(e.g :Pinned Url : youtube.com/anything : Ok so it’s YouTube : then replace the thumbnail with “Custom_Youtube_Thumbnail.png”)

Does that seems possible to you ? (Before I dive in head first)
I saw that the top-sites API is not quite available
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1246693 but maybe I’m wrong.

Extra : My extension is switching themes (like this :
https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/theme-switcher ).
Would it be possible to switch the thumbnails accordingly
(Custom_Youtube_Thumbnail_light.png > Custom_Youtube_Thumbnail_dark.png)
as i’ve made a version for each.

Would be a pleasure to hear your opinion on this, or just pointing
useful resources to me,
I’m not asking for a perfectly baked solution.
Hope I’ve been concise.

Thanks for reading me !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very nice idea you had.
But In short: no possible.

Main problem is that you cannot inject and manipulate on the homepage which is a built in browser tab.

"You cannot inject code into any of the browser's built-in pages, such as: about:debugging, about:addons, or the page that opens when you open a new empty tab."
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/executeScript

Comment: Arhg snap ! I feared this would be the case, I guess it's because security. Anyway I'll go creating a new tab/homecsreen from scratch now. Thanks for your answer !